# Count values in column on join then group by

Tags: mysql

Forgive me if this is super easy. I am doing some data analysis on the [Stack Overflow database model](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new). I need to count the number of badges a user has. They can have multiple of the same badge name.

For example:

A user can have 3 x Teacher badges, and 2 x Editor badges, etc.

I would like to be able to see it in the below format:

```
 UserName | Badge_Name | Amount
 ------------------------------
 JamesBond| Teacher    | 3
 JamesBond| Editor     | 2
 Arthur1  | Teacher    | 5
```

So far all I am able to retrieve is the display name of the user and the amount of badges they hold:

```sql
SELECT t2.DisplayName, COUNT(t1.Id) AS TotalNumberOfBadges
FROM Badges t1 
JOIN Users t2 ON t2.Id = t1.UserId 
GROUP BY t2.DisplayName 
ORDER BY t2.Id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the schema I've had to guess but it seems that you just need to add the Badge_Name to the SELECT list and the GROUP BY, like this:

```
SELECT t2.displayname AS UserName, t1.Badge_Name,
       Count(t1.id) AS TotalNumberOfBadges 
FROM   badges t1 
       join users t2 
         ON t2.id = t1.userid 
GROUP  BY t2.displayname, t1.Badge_Name
ORDER  BY t2.id;
```

If your badges table contains a different column name for the name of the badge you will have to sub that in for where I've used Badge_Name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact table layouts but you would either need to select the badge_name column from a table or use something like a badge_id inside a case statement.

```
SELECT t2.DisplayName,t1.Badge_Name, COUNT(t1.Id) AS TotalNumberOfBadges

FROM Badges t1

JOIN Users t2 ON t2.Id = t1.UserId

GROUP BY t2.DisplayName

ORDER BY t2.Id;
```

--case example

```
SELECT t2.DisplayName,
Case
WHEN badgeid=1 then 'Teacher'
WHEN badgeid=2 then 'Editor'
WHEN badgeid=3 then 'Commentor'
END
, COUNT(t1.Id) AS TotalNumberOfBadges

    FROM Badges t1

    JOIN Users t2 ON t2.Id = t1.UserId

    GROUP BY t2.DisplayName

    ORDER BY t2.Id;
```